# Converting Mono to a coroutine an then back again in WebFlux + Kotlin

Tags: spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor

I have a project with Spring WebFlux and normally we use Kotlin coroutines and don't see many `Mono` or `Flux` around. However, from time to time the need arises to integrate with the framework, like implement a custom `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` where only Project Reactor is known. I implemented such a method but it is very complex, unreadable, nobody understands it (arguably, WebFlux might not be the right choice for this team), and I won't understand it at first glance in a few days either, and it is really awful to step through while debugging. So I had the idea to do something like:

```kotlin
fun someFunction(fooMono: Mono<Foo>): Mono<Bar> {
  return mono {
    val foo = fooMono.awaitSingleOrNull()
    // do stuff
    Bar(...)
  }
}
```

which uses Reactor coroutines integration. The code (`do stuff` above) is then much (in my opinion) easier to understand and can actually be debugged.

Basically it converts a `Mono` to a coroutine and then back again. Is this a good idea? Is there a big performance penalty for doing so?